# How to implement Unary coding?

Tags: algorithm

I have a question about how to implement [unary encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_coding). For example: How can we differ *n* (non-negative) from *n* (strictly positive)? I don’t understand a bit. Please help me.

I have changed and written code.

```
public class unary {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int n = 10;
        int i = 0;
        String t = "";
        while (i<n) {
            t += "1";
            i++;
        }
        t += "0";
        System.out.println(n);
        System.out.println("unary representation:");
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
10
unary representation:
11111111110
```

Is it right like this?

Comment: If you get something like '111110' and you want to know what it corresponds to, you need to know the format in advance - non-negative or strictly positive.

Comment: 11111111110 is 10 or 11, depends if 0 is in your domain or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-negative natural numbers includes 0.
Strictly positive natural numbers does not.
You don't need to differ non-negative from strictly-positive it is all about definition.

Unary string 0 represents the first natural number which is 0 if the domain is non-negative numbers or 1 if the domain is strictly-positive numbers.

The number 10 is represented as `1111111110` while dealing with strictly positive numbers or `11111111110` while dealing non-negative numbers.